# ParseServer UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: parse-server

I just upgrade parse-server to 3.0.0,js-sdk to 2.1.0.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('delete_account', function(request) {
var user = request.user;
user.set("delete",true);
user.save(null,{useMasterKey:true}).then(function(user){
    return "account deleted,please logout";
}).catch(function (reason) {
    throw "delete fail";
});
```

when i call the function it says:

`(node:27120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: delete fail`

`(node:27120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)`

Comment: my guess is that there is nothing to catch your `throw "delete fail"` line .... what you should probably do is use the second argument to the handler (e.g.`function (request, response) {` .... and rather call `response.error ("delete fail")` in the catch block